# How can I paste values from two tibbles or dataframes together into a combined display table in R?

Tags: r

I am interested in displaying the values from two different tables as a combined table, with values and percentages displayed in the same cell.

I have two dataframes,

```
pf<-data.frame(alpha=c(17,42,19),beta=c(21,47,15),sea=c(19,43,21))
```

and

```
cf<-data.frame(alpha=c(417,242,119),beta=c(721,447,315),sea=c(819,443,921))
```

The percentages are housed in **pf** and the raw values for this year are in **cf**.

My desired output is:

```
desired<-data.frame(alpha=c("417 (17%)","242 (42%)","119 (19%)"),
                    beta=c("721 (21%)","447 (47%)","315 (15%)"),
                    sea=c("819 (19%)","443 (43%)","921 (21%)"))
```

which looks like:

```
      alpha      beta       sea
1 417 (17%) 721 (21%) 819 (19%)
2 242 (42%) 447 (47%) 443 (43%)
3 119 (19%) 315 (15%) 921 (21%)
```

I am hoping for a solution that does not require explicitly typing column names "alpha" etc. in the code, as my columns will change names when pointed at difference source files.  The number of rows will also change, though pf and cf will always match one another in terms of dimensions.

It seems as though multiplication or other basic math functions where both tables are treated in relation to one another are easy (i.e pf*cf quickly returns a table of the values where relational multiplication is performed).

At this point, I've been experimenting with paste0() but getting unworkable results.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

An option in `base` you use `mapply` and `paste0`:

```
as.data.frame(mapply(function(x, y) paste0(x, "(", y, "%)"), cf, pf))

     alpha     beta      sea
1 417(17%) 721(21%) 819(19%)
2 242(42%) 447(47%) 443(43%)
3 119(19%) 315(15%) 921(21%)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `map2` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map2_df(cf, pf, ~ sprintf("%d (%d%%)", .x, .y))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#    alpha     beta      sea      
#   <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
#1 417 (17%) 721 (21%) 819 (19%)
#2 242 (42%) 447 (47%) 443 (43%)
 #3 119 (19%) 315 (15%) 921 (21%)
```

Or if it is float, then we can `round`

```
map2_df(cf, pf, ~ sprintf("%d (%f%%)", .x, round(.y, 2)))
```

Comment: In my data, some percentages take the form of 19.567261% etc.  Is there a way to adjust this to display something like "47 (19.57%)"?

Comment: @Pake Updated the posst